# Diagnosing DLL issues with SDL2 and MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, dll, sdl, mingw32

I'm trying to get a simple SDL2 application I wrote up and running but there seems to be a problem with SDL2 on my computer. I am running 64-bit Windows 8.1 Pro with all MS Visual Studio C++ 2013 libraries installed (x64 *and* x86) and Windows fully updated. SDL2 worked fine on my old computer with a similar setup (I recently re-installed Windows) so I am at a loss to explain this error.

**TL;DR: Simple test code I have written fails cryptically when loading a DLL from C:\Windows\System32. How can I diagnose DLL loading issues on Windows?**

**Test Code**

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
LIBRARY_PATHS=-LC:\MinGW\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
LIBRARY_INC=-IC:\MinGW\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
CXX = mingw32-g++
CXXFLAGS=-g
LIBRARY_FLAGS=-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows

main.exe: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_INC) -o main.exe main.cpp $(LIBRARY_FLAGS)

clean:
    rm main.exe
```

**Compiling and Running**

```
D:\Projects\sdl-test
$ mingw32-make
cc -LC:\MinGW\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -IC:\MinGW\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -o main.exe main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
D:\Projects\sdl-test
? gdb .\main.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from D:\Projects\sdl-test\main.exe...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: D:\Projects\sdl-test/.\main.exe
[New Thread 3136.0xae4]
warning: SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)

gdb: unknown target exception 0xc000007b at 0x7758d4f2
During startup program exited with code 0xc000007b.
(gdb) quit
```

After much Googling I figured out that the error code given (0xc000007b) is related to loading DLLs, so I checked the Event Viewer:

**Event Logs**

```
Event Viewer:
Faulting application name: main.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x02d2e568
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17736, time stamp: 0x550f42c2
Exception code: 0xc000007b
Fault offset: 0x0009d4f2
Faulting process id: 0xc40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0a1729dcec24e
Faulting application path: D:\Projects\sdl-test\main.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: db8737d8-0d65-11e5-8268-c4d987e72ee3
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

From another log:

```
Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program main.exe because of this error.

Program: main.exe
File: 

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: 00000000
Disk type: 0
```

ntdll.dll is where I've lost the trail; I cannot figure out why my program crashes when loading this DLL. Programs such as ProcMon and DependencyWalker have failed to tell me anything, and I can't seem to find any official Microsoft documentation on what ntdll.dll does or how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure that version of SDL2 DLLs were compiled with `g++`? Are you also sure there aren't any weird exception things going on? Are you sure that it also uses the right flavor of MinGW? There's often TDM-GCC, MinGW, and MinGW-w64 (I like w64 because it doesn't have bugs with tostring() and <chrono> and stuff.)

Comment: I got the SDL2 DLLs (and everything else) from [this page](http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) (see SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz). I got MinGW from [this page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) which I'm almost certain is the 32bit version. Everything should be 32 bit then, in theory. As for what the DLLs were compiled with, I don't know.

Comment: You could try and compile SDL yourself, or you could try and redownload the DLLs. You can also try to make sure the linking order is correct.

Comment: Related: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/programs-close-faulting-module-ntdlldll/54aaaec5-2b53-4e9f-b9a7-b7889a1cd4b6

Answer (score 2):

Got it! For some reason, including *SDL2.dll*, *SDL2_image.dll*, and *SDL2_ttf.dll* in the same folder as the running application is not enough. I guess Windows still couldn't find them. What I had to do was copy the contents of **SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\bin** to **C:\Windows\System32**.

I imagine there is a better way of doing this; filling up your windir with random DLLs sounds like a great way to mess something up in the future, but for now this works.

Comment: I didn't get any results from putting `SDL2.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32`. Also, I get the same error if I link statically.

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising that putting SDL2 in the same directory as main.exe does not work.

Put the SDL2 dll's in the same directory as your .exe, or add the directory SDL2 is in to PATH, or for MingW you might be able to set LIBRARY_PATH to the directory containing the dll's.